# Can We Have 0 Normal Between Any Two Bodies Just Touching Each Other

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, string

I am a bit confused...

[image]

Here if we see x-axis forces they are getting detached from each other. So To Resist them The Normal Should Be Zero.
I am not sure if I am applying the right logic or not
but my sir gave me an example of two balls just touching each other and having normal = 0 between them... I don't know the reason. if you can explain this then it will be appreciable

Here is the example which sir gave us
[image]

here Normal Between B and C is 0. Please Explain How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal force is of electromagnatic nature (in the view of classical mechanics), generally understood as a force that prevents bodies from "falling" into each other, or merging into each other. This only comes into picture when there is a counter force that pushes bodies against each other. Example, gravity pushing a ball towards the ground, and the ground repulses this ball, with a force that is equal and opposite (we draw this conclusions from the fact that the ball is not in accelerated motion along the common normal). In the example case you've given, there is no force that "pushes" B into C, or vice versa. There is a normal force on both B and C, independently from A, whose horizontal components actually cause a force on B, away from C, and a force on C away from B, hence no reason for normal force to exist.